# importXML parsing error presumably due to structure

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets, formulas

I am trying to read some data from an online POS-database, and the data is ordered in XML with a relatively modest amount of data per line nor any special characters that could cause anything weird to happen.

Yet when I use the =importXML-function, the 'Imported XML Content Cannot Be Parsed' error occurs. Using =importdata instead works perfectly, but I would really like to be able to use xpath in order to lighten the load of calculations and programming.

A sample from a browser-visit to the API returns the following for a narrow selection of time:

```
35720.08.201513:32Iced latteCoffee and Tea125,00Cash00Terminal 1 35820.08.201513:39Cappuccino largeCoffee and Tea120,00Cash00Terminal 1 35820.08.201513:39FOC 20Coffee and Tea1-20,00Cash00Terminal 1 35920.08.201513:50btl waterSoda etc115,00Card00Terminal 1 36020.08.201513:51PostmixSoda etc115,00Card00Terminal 1
```

Whereas =importdata returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<XML>
<sales>
<line id="965848892794"><chk>357</chk><date>20.08.2015</date><time>13:32</time><product id="271220">Iced latte</product><product_group id="13494">Coffee and Tea</product_group><amount>1</amount><price>25 00</price><payment_type>Cash</payment_type><clerk>0</clerk><pax>0</pax><department>Terminal 1</department><ean ean_1="" ean_2="" ean_3="" ean_4="" /></line>
<line id="965848893275"><chk>358</chk><date>20.08.2015</date><time>13:39</time><product id="271218">Cappuccino large</product><product_group id="13494">Coffee and Tea</product_group><amount>1</amount><price>20   00</price><payment_type>Cash</payment_type><clerk>0</clerk><pax>0</pax><department>Terminal 1</department><ean ean_1="" ean_2="" ean_3="" ean_4="" /></line>
<line id="965848893276"><chk>358</chk><date>20.08.2015</date><time>13:39</time><product id="271310">FOC 20</product><product_group id="13494">Coffee and Tea</product_group><amount>1</amount><price>-20    00</price><payment_type>Cash</payment_type><clerk>0</clerk><pax>0</pax><department>Terminal 1</department><ean ean_1="" ean_2="" ean_3="" ean_4="" /></line>
<line id="965848893960"><chk>359</chk><date>20.08.2015</date><time>13:50</time><product id="271206">btl water</product><product_group id="13493">Soda etc</product_group><amount>1</amount><price>15    00</price><payment_type>Card</payment_type><clerk>0</clerk><pax>0</pax><department>Terminal 1</department><ean ean_1="" ean_2="" ean_3="" ean_4="" /></line>
<line id="965848894015"><chk>360</chk><date>20.08.2015</date><time>13:51</time><product id="271199">Postmix</product><product_group id="13493">Soda etc</product_group><amount>1</amount><price>15  00</price><payment_type>Card</payment_type><clerk>0</clerk><pax>0</pax><department>Terminal 1</department><ean ean_1="" ean_2="" ean_3="" ean_4="" /></line>
</sales></XML>
```

I have tried all the suggested replies on the page but everyone seems to have made it further it the 'problem-process' than this. I asked the POS company whether they had any problems with the XML structure and the answer was negative. Please note that I have had zero formal education on programming, so the answer might be straight forward.

NOTE: The API cannot return anything without my confidential login credentials, which obviously have to be kept out of the public eye. But I can provide you with any data you want, if the existing is not appropriate.

Comment: What is the URL and the xPath that you are trying? Reference: [mcve].

Comment: Hi Ruben, any at all xPaths are unsuccessful, referring to other solutions on Stackoverflow. "*" or something much more specific provides the same result, 'Imported XML Content Cannot Be Parsed'

Comment: Do you not want to share the URL? Why?

Comment: Hi Ruben, it is as mentioned an API where you cannot return anything without my confidential login credentials, which obviously have to be kept out of the public eye. But I can provide you with any data you want, if the existing is not appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMPORTXML only is able to access content available without a requiring authentication, in other available for those who knows the URL without required them to sign in first. An alternative is to use Url Fetch Service from Google Apps Script.

Related Q&A

- [Login using UrlFetchApp function and scrape private data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41060098/1595451)
- [Import private data into Google Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24140411/1595451)

Comment: Thank you Ruben, I'll try that instead.